Why is clone-indirect-buffer-other-window not a clone?
I find that a clone created this way is not including the beginning of the buffer, probably because the buffer is large?
Is there some setting that clones the entire buffer, without leaving parts of the buffer out?

You can at least include some minimal information that would allow somebody else to try it and see. The documentation says nothing about size limitations or options to set, so I assume you are doing something wrong. But without any information (is there an error message? how large is the buffer that fails to clone properly?) there is no way to know for sure.

FWIW, I opened a 100MB PDF file and cloned the buffer with no problems.
